# Translate this SELECT to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to translate this SELECT to ActiveRecord but I don't get the desire result. Can you help me? The SELECT is:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM (SELECT recipients.lang,COUNT(name) AS quantity FROM messages, recipients WHERE messages.lang=recipients.lang AND active=1 GROUP BY lang) AS temp;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: sometimes its good to just use find_by_sql. Its faster.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of object does this return ? Shreyas solution find_by_sql seems better.